# unable to compile a servlet in ubuntu

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am newbie to j2ee. I have download and installed j2eesdk-1_4_03-linux.bin in my ubuntu 10.04 distribution. and then i tried to code my first servlet in it as:

```
    import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HowdyServlet extends HttpServlet{
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                out.println("<html>");
                out.println("<head><title>howdy</title></head>");
                out.println("<body>");
                out.println("<center><h1>Howdy</h1></center>");
                out.println("</body>");
                out.println("</html>");
        }
}
```

and here are the environment variables i set after installation:

```
1. J2EE_HOME=/home/vinit/SUNWappserver
2. JAVA_HOME=/home/vinit/SUNWappserver/jdk
3. CLASSPATH=/home/vinit/SUNWappserver/lib
```

and now i tried to compile the servlet using

```
javac HowdyServelet.java
```

But i got following errors:

```
HowdyServlet.java:2: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
^
HowdyServlet.java:3: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.*;
^
HowdyServlet.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol: class HttpServlet
public class HowdyServlet extends HttpServlet{
                                  ^
HowdyServlet.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class HowdyServlet
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
                          ^
HowdyServlet.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
location: class HowdyServlet
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
                                                      ^
HowdyServlet.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class HowdyServlet
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
                                                                                                        ^
6 errors
```

So how to compile this servlet. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `CLASSPATH=/home/vinit/SUNWappserver/lib` has no desired effect; you have to name each JAR you want on the classpath individually.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. by setting classpath to individual jar

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to compile it until you change `servelet` to `servlet`